# Abrir javascript no handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, handlebars.js

Estou fazendo um sistema utilizando o Handlebars no NodeJS, quando tento pegar meu código javascript por ele, ele não o encontra.
A solução que encontrei foi enviar meu javascript como uma pagina pelo node e depois pega-lo pelo localhost, porem acredito que não seja a melhor solução.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/mudartexto.js"></script>
       
    
    
    <title>postagens Node.js</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

erro: 
 GET http://localhost:8081/js/mudartexto.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: você verificou o caminho? como está a estrutura da sua aplicação?

Comment: sim, o caminho esta correto, testei de outra forma e tudo indica que esta correto

Answer (score 1):

Para você conseguir adicionar arquivos estáticos na sua aplicação você irá precisar uma função do `Express` chamada `static`

Carregue 1º sua pasta de arquivos estáticos

Exemplo:

```
app.use(express.static('app/public'))
```

Depois em seu arquivo `.handlebars` carregue ele de acordo com o diretório

```
<script src="/js/index.js"></script>
```

Coloquei um `alert` para verificar se carregou o arquivo corretamente

```
alert('Arquivo de função carregado com sucesso!')
```

Como está minha estrutura de arquivos

[image: Estrutura de Arquivos]

Página rodando

[image: Página rodando]

Comment: não esta funcionando, acredito que por estar utilizando no node ele tente buscar o javascript por um site, o que estou fazendo é jogar ele para uma pagina e assim consigo acessar normalmente.

Comment: Você baixou o framework express? Ou só baixou o express-hadlebars?

Comment: Sim, os dois estão funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Como o handlebars é um script, ele nao irá reconhecer o outro script dentro dele.
O que você pode fazer é: "escapar" a tag script.
Ficaria assim:

```
<script src="seuscript.js"><{{!}}/script>
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: infelizmente não funcionou, mas obrigado assim mesmo.